# PHP: 3 int IDs within 1 int variable

Tags: php

I'm having to pass 3 variables (int) within a single numeric string called $id. To do this I'm creating $id using padding which I can then explode to get the variables. It has to be numeric otherwise I'd use underscores between the variables. I'm using eleven zeros as padding as I know the variables won't have that many zeros. So currently if I have:

```
$int_one = 1;
$int_two = 2;
$int_three = 3;
```

That would be:

```
$id = "1000000000002000000000003";
```

To create the new Id I use:

```
$id = $int_one . "00000000000" . $int_two . "00000000000" . $int_three;
```

And to separate the Id I use:

```
$int_one = 0;
$int_two = 0;
$int_three = 0;
if (strpos($id,"00000000000") !== false) {
    $id = strrev($id); // Reversed so 0's in int's don't get counted
    $id = explode("00000000000", $id);
    // Set numbers back the right way
    $int_one = strrev($id[2]);
    $int_two = strrev($id[1]);
    $int_three = strrev($id[0]);
}
```

This runs into problems when an individual variables is 0. Is there a way to overcome this or does it need a major rethink?

**EDIT:** `$id` is supposed to be a numeric string not int

Needs to handle int variables between 0 - 2147483647

Comment: Do you really mean an int, or just a numeric string? An int is (on a 32 bit machine) limited to 32 bits, a maximum of ~9 digits total, so your padding will make it overflow.

Comment: Use different padding? Like 123456789 or if you want bigger number 987654321

Comment: What if you need that number at some point?

Comment: The three variables going in and coming out need to be int. But yes the $id only has to be a numeric string. I'll update the post to be more specific.

Comment: The question has a requirement for int. While I don't know the reasoning behind this decision - this is what he asked.

Comment: I've tried with a padding of 98765456789 and that seems to work. The pattern can't appear within the three int variables so shouldn't cause any problems. I think

Comment: @RebDev Did you try my solution that generates shorter ints and does not use padding that can be confused with the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use some string magic to assure that no number has more than one zero in a row, and delimit the values using '00'. This generates a *numeric string* that can be uniquely decoded no matter the size or composition of the ints.

```
$a = 100;
$b = 0;
$c = 120;

// Encode;

$id = str_replace('0', '01', $a).'00'
     .str_replace('0', '01', $b).'00'
     .str_replace('0', '01', $c);

// $id = "101010001001201"

// Decode;

$tmp = split('00', $id);
$a2 = intval(str_replace('01', '0', $tmp[0]));
$b2 = intval(str_replace('01', '0', $tmp[1]));
$c2 = intval(str_replace('01', '0', $tmp[2]));

// $a2 = 100, $b2 = 0, $c2 = 120
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to overcome this or does it need a major rethink?

Yes, you'll need to rethink that. Why do you need to do it that way? Simply create a function with three parameters and pass the three ints in:

```
function foo($int1, $int2, $int3) {
}
```

Your example uses strings, not ints by the way, so you aren't even following your own requirements.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it has to be done this way. I need a single int $id variable that can be split into three int variables that can be 0.

Comment: You don't present a reasoning why it has to be done that way, could you add the code that actually uses this procedure to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method:

```
$int_one = 1;
$int_two = 2;
$int_three = 3;

$id = $int_one * 1000000000000 + $int_two * 1000000 + $int_three;
// This will create a value of 1000002000003
```

To reverse the process:

```
// Get the modulo of $id / 1000000 --> 3
$int_three = $id % 1000000;

// Recalculate the base id - if you would like to retain the original id, first duplicate variable
// This would make $id = 1000002;
$id = ($id - $int_three) / 1000000;

// Again, get modulo --> 2
$int_two = $id % 1000000;

// Recalculate base id
$id = ($id - $int_two) / 1000000;

// Your first integer is the result of this division.
$int_one = $id;
```

Comment: Would that work if the input variables are max int 2147483647?

Comment: You can always make the multiplication using a larger number... It was just to show the principle.